# Generate a "reverse" index

Tags: indexing

For reviewing purposes, I'd like to generate a "reverse" index, that would list all the keys per page, instead of the pages per key.

That is, *in addition* to generating the normal index:

> key1.......... 1, 3, 5
>
> key2.......... 2, 4, 5

I'd like:

> 1: key1
>
> 2: key2
>
> 3: key1
>
> 4: key2
>
> 5: key1, key2

Is that possible?

Comment: are you using the regular `\index{...}` entry method?  if so, it should be possible to do something "sensible" with the `.idx` file(s) that are generated automatically -- they're already in page number order.  i don't know that anyone has done such a thing, but i look into such files all the time to check the input when problems arise.

Comment: Do you use xindy? Please add a mwe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

It isn't really a reverse as it is the order the items are collected, it is `makeindex` that does the reversal to make the normal index.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx} 
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{main}
aaa\index{ho} bbb\index{foo}  cc\index{grrr}

\clearpage

aaa\index{ho} bbb\index{foo}  cc\index{grrr}

aaa\index{zho} bbb\index{zfoo}  cc\index{zgrrr}

\clearpage

aaa\index{bho} bbb\index{foo}  cc\index{grrr}



{\clearpage
\section*{xedni}
\makeatletter
\immediate\closeout\@indexfile
\def\lastp{}
\def\indexentry#1#2{%
\def\thisp{#2}%
\ifx\thisp\lastp
\unskip, %
\else
\let\lastp\thisp
\item[#2: ]%
\fi
#1}

\begin{itemize}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.idx}{}{}
\end{itemize}
}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't support entries like `\index{abc@abd|see{abx}}` though.

Comment: well it does _something_ . Define "support"

Comment: Yes, that's hard to support and I guess it does what I described in the question :-)

Comment: @ℝaphink you could typest `#1` in tt or pseudo-verbatim if you wanted to show the markup, or you could add some macro parsing to dicard the `|see` bit or do something with `@` but it isn't clear in general what is best (and doing nothing is easiest)